# GDStar Plugin - Does not show Rating if the user has already voted

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out a way to show the thumb up image, which currently shows "only" in the mouseover state, after the user has voted.

Similar to Stackoverflow after the page is refreshed the orange upvote thing shows up if I've already voted for the question. In GD star the block only becomes inactive but does not show if the visitor/user has already voted and whether he thumbed up or down. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use post meta. When a user click Vote, you should add a meta to that post like this:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'voted', 1);
```

And every time you display a post you should get it's meta using:

$isVoted = get_post_meta($post_id, 'voted', true);

and check the $isVoted variable value:

```
if ($isVoted == '1') {

    //you will show an image stating that the post was voted
} else {

    //you will show the Vote button
}
```

Here you find some info about [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) and [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).